# How savind data from model?

Tags: yii2

I don`t understand how savind data from model (like User.php)
**When i run saveData()  from Controller new row not creared.**

```
class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
   ....
   public function saveData() {
      $this->name = 'test_user';
      $this->save();
   }
}
```

I don`t want save data from controller.
What i do wrong?

Comment: Your question is unclear please rephrase it

Comment: @legrandviking You mean **uncrear**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if there are validation errors:

```
class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
   ....
   public function saveData() {
      $this->name = 'test_user';
      if($this->save() == false)
      {
            var_dump($this->errors);
      }
   }
}
```